# How to check if any of the Objects have the same data for the same field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unique, irb

Is there a sweet `irb` line of code that could check is any of the `Object`'s have the same data in their field?

For example, could I see if any of the `Object`'s have the same email? Alternatively, check and see if any of the objects are not unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it this way:

Create a hash with all instance variables as key-value pairs and then compare the hashes:

Assuming you have two objects a and b:

```
hash_a = a.instance_variables.inject({}){|res,v| res[v] = a.instance_variable_get(v); res }
hash_b = b.instance_variables.inject({}){|res,v| res[v] = b.instance_variable_get(v); res }

if hash_a == hash_b 
  puts "equal"
else
  puts "not equal"
end
```

**Edit**:

If you are talking about Rails Models then you need this:

```
if a.attributes == b.attributes
  puts "equal"
end
```

Comment: Ah thanks sled. I'm gonna wait around a bit more to see if there's something really sexy. But thanks this works!